# Check file checksum before deciding to download

Tags: javascript, rest, service-worker

I want to implement the following logic: fetch the big file (up to 100MB) and store it in the service worker. Then I want to check periodically (say once per hour) and if the remote file changes - need to re-download it. 
Otherwise - I don't want to disturb the server.

I was thinking about sending something like 'OPTIONS' request, just to get checksum of the file.

How could I tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [HTTP Conditional Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Conditional_requests). Here's a way you could implement this:

- Configure the server to include a `Last-Modified` response header with the date when the requested file was last modified and to respond with `304 Not Modified` if the file was not modified since the date indicated by the `If-Modified-Since` request header.
- Make the service worker save the value of the `Last-Modified` header and use it in the next requests to the file. If the server returns a `304 Not Modified`, it means that the cached file is still up-to-date. If the server returns `200 OK`, cache that file and store the value of the `Last-Modified` header.

You can also use ETags with `If-None-Match`.

This is the standard way to handle caching with HTTP.